# Unexpected token admin.php

Tags: forms, admin-menu

when submit a form , it's seems that nothing happen and all i have to troubleshoot are these errors in the console log:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    admin.php?page=wprm_importing:271 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    admin.php?page=wprm_importing:313
```

i don't understand what it means.
does anyone faced this kind of message ?

Comment: Sounds like the form is being submitted/processed via AJAX, and the AJAX response body wasn't a valid output. [This may help you.](https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: To add to @SallyCJ's comment, the invalid output could be error output or html content. If your ajax isn't expecting this type of response, it would throw an error like this. For example, if your ajax response is set to expect json, anything containing `<` would be in an incorrect format.